# How to convert .jpg file into .bmp file in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one .jpg image, which I picked from ImagePicker Library, and I want to convert that file into .bmp file in flutter.

I have tried with native library but I didn't get proper solution.

I want to perform this for Android and Ios

Answer (score 2):

This is a very bad idea, and there is no benefit in converting a compressed format (JPG) into an uncompressed one (BMP). The opposite would make more sense.

The resulting BMP image will take way more space than the original, the quality doesn't improve in any way, and you won't be able to use it as efficiently in an app, or in the web, because it will make everything run slower.

Sometimes, just because we can do something, doesn't mean we should.

Comment: I was thinking that while looking at the question.  Why would anything inside flutter need a BMP file?

Answer (score 1):

I converted 'tiff' to 'png' with 'opencv'.
Try changing the path of `tiff` to `bmp` and the path of `png` to `jpg`.

Write code after linking opencv to `android` and `ios` respectively.

**android**

```
                try {
                    Mat tiffImg = Imgcodecs.imread(strTiff/*, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR*/);

                    //change background alpha
                    Mat gray = new Mat();

                    Imgproc.cvtColor(tiffImg, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                    Mat mask = new Mat();
                    Imgproc.threshold(gray, mask, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

                    List<Mat> bgra = new ArrayList<Mat>(4);
                    Core.split(tiffImg, bgra);
                    bgra.add(mask);

                    Mat dst = new Mat();
                    Core.merge(bgra, dst);

                    //Writr png
                    boolean res = Imgcodecs.imwrite(pngPath, dst);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

**IOS**

```
NSString* tiffName = [strName stringByAppendingString:@".tiff"];
          
          NSString* readFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:tiffName];
          
          UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strTiff];

          cv::String tiffPath = [readFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

          //Read Tiff
          cv::Mat tiffImage;
          UIImageToMat(image, tiffImage, true);
          
          //Change Background Alpha
          cv::Mat input_bgra;
          cv::cvtColor(tiffImage, input_bgra, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
          for (int y = 0; y < input_bgra.rows; ++y)
              for (int x = 0; x < input_bgra.cols; ++x)
              {
                  cv::Vec4b & pixel = input_bgra.at<cv::Vec4b>(y, x);
                  // if pixel is white
                  if (pixel[0] == 255 && pixel[1] == 255 && pixel[2] == 255)
                  {
                      // set alpha to zero:
                      pixel[3] = 0;
                  }
              }
          
        
          NSString* pngName = [strName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
          NSString* saveFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pngName];
          //Write PNG
          cv::String writepath_str = [saveFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          bool res = cv::imwrite(writepath_str, input_bgra);
```

`//Change Background Alpha` is the code that makes the background transparent. It doesn't matter if you don't write any code if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function to convert the jpg to bmp

```
void convertJpgToBmp(String jpgPath, String bmpPath) {
  final File jpgFile = File(jpgPath);
  final img.Image jpgImage = img.decodeImage(jpgFile.readAsBytesSync());

  final img.Image bmpImage = img.Image.from(jpgImage);

  final File bmpFile = File(bmpPath);
  bmpFile.writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeBmp(bmpImage));
}

void main() {
  final String jpgFilePath = 'test.jpg';
  final String bmpFilePath = 'converted.bmp';

  convertJpgToBmp(jpgFilePath, bmpFilePath);

  print('Convert completed.');
}
```

Comment: This Chat-Gpt Solution is not working.

Comment: I've tried this code for same thing a month ago. It worked for me... Sorry, if its not helped you. @JaimisDomadiya

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/bitmap
This problem seems to be solved with a 3rd party plugin.According to this package:

```
Bitmap bitmap = await Bitmap.fromProvider(NetworkImage("http://pudim.com.br/pudim.jpg")); // convert from Network Image
Bitmap.fromProvider(AssetImage("assets/images/random.jpg")); // convert from your assets
```

I hope the problem is solved. Enjoy your work.